# between Binary and Ternary (or Higher-Degree) Relationships

Tags: database, uml

What are the differences between an Binary Relationship and a Ternary or Higher Degree Relationships ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `binary` relation is used when two entities have relation directly with each other, here directly is mean a key on child relation should refer to a value which is available on parent table identity/unique key. something like this.
[image]
The `Ternary`, when three or (n) relations have relationship between themselves, and providing all relationship between them makes the database complex, so here the relationships will turned into a relation which has one-to-many/one-to-one with base relations.
example: consider an event in OS, an event would associate with `application` which registered the event, the `device` which caused the event, and the `component`(textbox, button, window,...) which triggered the event.
[image]